# Declaring Variable in Verilog with Indexing that doesn't start at zero

Tags: verilog, hdl, register-transfer-level

I am using this wire declaration in Verilog:

```
wire [23:15] myvar;
```

My code works and I have seen this coding style before, but I am not sure what is actually happening, I can only guess that a wire that is 9 bits wide is getting declared. Is that what is happening? I wanted to read more on this online, but i didn't know what this is called, so apologies for the simplistic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you are declaring a 9-bit wire. Many designs have different ideas about what the LSB and MSB values should be, which direction the index numbering should go in. It really doesn't matter what use for index values until you start referencing individual bit or slices.

Answer (score 4):

Verilog is a Hardware Descriptive Language(HDL). Whatever you write/declare, ultimately turns out to be a form of **hardware**.

Lets have a look at the image below:

[image: wire indexing]

Here, declaring `wire [23:15] myvar;` or `wire [8:0] myvar;` declares the same **bunch of wires, nine bits wide**. Its just the **indexing part** that differs. No matter you call it as `a[0]` (when `a` is `wire [8:0] a`) or `a[15]` (when `a` is `wire [23:15] a`). The coding part is different according to the *ease* for programmer, while **synthesis part** remains the **same**.

Also, note that in *former* case, `myvar[15]` is the least significant bit while *latter* has `myvar[0]` as the LSB. We can swap the declarations part, which shall swap the MSB-LSB too.

```
reg  [7:0] reg1;    // 8-bit vector with MSB=7 LSB=0
reg  [0:7] reg2;    // 8-bit vector with MSB=0 LSB=7
// ...
// ...
reg1 = 8'hF0; // reg1[7] = 1 and reg1[0] = 0 ultimately, reg1 = F0
reg2 = 8'hF0; // reg2[7] = 0 and reg2[0] = 1 ultimately, reg2 = F0
```

Lets take an example:

```
wire [23:15] myvar;
reg [23:15] reg2;
reg [31:0] reg3;
initial begin
    $monitor("myvar = %0h myvar2 = %0h reg3 = %0h",myvar,myvar2,reg3);
    reg3 = 32'h5ABC_FEDC;

// This will correctly assign values to reg2, since it is [23:15]
    for(int i=16;i<20;i++)
      begin
      reg2[i] = myvar[i];
        $display("1: reg2[%0d] = %0h myvar[%0d] = %0h",i,reg2[i],i,myvar[i]);
      end

// While, this will not assign correctly, 
// since reg2 does not have [5:0] indexes,neither does myvar
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
      begin
      reg2[i] = myvar[i];
        $display("2: reg2[%0d] = %0h myvar[%0d] = %0h",i,reg2[i],i,myvar[i]);
      end
  end
```

Another alternative is that your `reg` is `[8:0]` while `wire` is `[23:0]`. Here ***is*** all that matters, but ***just in the coding part***. Note that in the *first* snippet below, values are assigned to `reg1[4:0]` and in the *second* snippet, it is in the range `reg1[20:15]`.

```
reg [8:0] reg1;
wire [23:15] myvar;
// Correct, since LSB of myvar is at index position 15
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
      begin
        reg1[i] = myvar[i+15];
        $display("3 : reg1[%0d] = %0h myvar[%0d] = %0h",i,reg1[i],i,myvar[i+15]);
      end

reg [31:0] reg1;
wire [23:15] myvar;
// reg1[19:15] is assigned here
for(int i=15;i<20;i++)
      begin
        reg1[i] = myvar[i];
        $display("4 : reg1[%0d] = %0h myvar[%0d] = %0h",i,reg1[i],i,myvar[i]);
      end
```

So, in the end, just some **slicing** differs while driving from the wire, no effect on the **actual hardware**. More information can be obtained from [Verilog Syntax Details](http://www.verilogtutorial.info/chapter_3.htm) link.